# I need to edit some "default arguments" not all of them, how can I do that?

Tags: python, function, args

So lets begin from the beginning. In python you can write functions with many arguments, some of them are "editable" and some of them are initiated by default. Usually default arguments are located at the very end of the function's argument.

Assume I have many default parameters, and I want to edit for the exercise only one of them that its not the first one .

lets use the next example:

```
foo(val_1,val_2,val_3=0,val_4=1,val_5='true')
    sth here
return sth else
```

So here I need to define before the function

```
val_1,val_2
```

the other arguments are defaulted.... how can I change:

```
val_5,
```

or

```
val_4,
```

with out needing to write the whole function

```
foo(val_1,val_2,val_3=0,val_4=10,val_5='false')
```

Is it possible to write something like:

```
foo(val_1,val_2, ,val_4=10,val_5='false')
```

(the value of val_3 is missing)

Comment: Can you provide the definition of your function `foo`? If `val_3` is defined with a default argument, then that should work fine (omitting the space for it as well)

Comment: If you have many default params, consider using ** kwargs instead

Comment: How does the ```foo``` function look like? What do you mean by default values? Because for the moment I don't see any default values. Perhaps you wanted to have: ```def foo(val_1, val_2, val_3=0, val_4=10, val_5="false")```. This way you only need to call ```foo(val_1=1, val_2=2)```

Comment: for example this function from scipy,

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html

I want to edit only the "tolerance" with out altering "fprime" and "args()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, when you specify a default value for an argument, you make it a **named variable**.

If you declare a method with the following prototype:

```
foo(val_1, val_2, val_3=0, val_4=10, val_5='false')
```

Then `val_3`, `val_4` and `val_5` are named variables with default values of `0`, `10` and `'false'` accordingly.

When you call this method, you can **omit** any one of them. So any of the following calls is legit:

```
foo(x, y)

foo(x, y, val_3=3)

foo(x, y, val_3=1, val_5='haha')
```

Any unspecified argument will have its default value.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the function as

```
def foo(val_1,val_2,val_3=0,val_4=1,val_5='true'):
    #whatever code you want
```

then running following commands should not cause any error

```
print(foo(1,2,val_4=7,val_5='false'))
print(foo(1,2,val_3=6,val_4=9))
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use somethinig like this:

```
def foo(val1, val2 = None, **kwargs):
   return val1, val2, kwargs

print (foo(1))
(1, None, {})
print (foo(1, val3="no declared argument"))
(1, None, {'val3': 'no declared argument'})
```

kwargs is a dict with the parameters that you passed to your function 'foo'. The arguments with a default value must to be after the arguments without it. And always at the end, **kwargs o **args. args is an array with the arguments without explicit declaration in the function, and kwargs is the dict.